# firebase deploy is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I was working with cloud function and It was doing great. Then I want to compile java program and install another extention on vscode.

*notes : I changed my PATH

**But now, if I want to firebase deploy my cloud function its going like this**

[image: Screen Shot]

**This is my firecast folder**

[image: Screen Shot]

[image]

Comment: It seems like firebase command is not in you PATH

Comment: I changed my path before

Comment: where is your firebase.exe command?

Comment: I dont know sir

Comment: Look I din't have the joy to play with Firecast, but I've used Firebase with an Android app and to use the firebase-tools cli you have to install it first `https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/`. If you already done that, It seems that the install procedure did not put the firebase-tools in your PATH, so you cannot launch them.

Comment: all firebase, cli, node.js are installed correctly. It was work perfectly until now it missing like that

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't seem so... your command prompt are telling you that It cannot find firebase.exe. Try reinstalling them or add them to your PATH variable

Comment: so how to fix it?

Comment: Try reinstalling them or add them to your PATH variable

Comment: what should i add to the path?

Comment: If you have installed firebase-tool with global (-g) you should have firebase.exe in your `%HOMEPATH%\AppData\Roaming\npm` folder. Otherwise you have installed it local when you did it. But I suggest you to reinstall firebase tools with ( -g) option and give it a try.

Comment: I did all of your suggest, but it still have the same error

Comment: Did you reinstall with these command? `npm install -g firebase-tools`

Comment: If you type `where firebase` what do you see?

Comment: sure, I did that command twice

Comment: nowwww it worksss!

Comment: You gotcha, bro!

Comment: Well done, c ya!

Comment: I've posted my comment as an answer, so if you like you can accept it as answer and upvote that ;-)

Comment: Hi! Is there something wrong with my answer you didn’t accept it as the correct one? I’d really appreciate if all my effort to help you will end up with some feedback ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like `firebase.exe` command is not in you `PATH`

If you have installed firebase-tool with global (`-g`) you should have `firebase.exe` in your `%HOMEPATH%\AppData\Roaming\npm` folder.

Otherwise you have installed it local when you did it. But I suggest you to reinstall firebase tools with (`-g`) option and give it a try.

Then try also `where firebase` to see if now it could be find in your `PATH`.

Answer (score 1):

Do it using npm it is much simpler

```
1) npm i -g firebase-cli

2) firebase login

3) firebase init

4) to run local test its firebase serve --only functions,hosting     
(if use using hosting)

5) firebase deploy
```